# python:Difference between Iterables and generator and yield in python?

Tags: python, generator, yield-keyword

I came across these terms *iterables*, *generator* and *yield* while solving the following problem which uses the `yield` keyword:

> **question:** Define a class with a generator which can iterate the numbers, which are divisible by 7, between a given range 0 and n.
>
> **Solution:**
>
> ```
> def putNumbers(n):
>     i = 0
>     while i<n:
>         j=i
>         i=i+1
>         if j%7==0:
>             yield j
>         for i in reverse(100):
>             print i
> ```

I didn't understand why `yield` is used here.
I have gone through [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) to also understand.

and raise one more question since both the code for iterables and generators gives same output.

code for iterables:

```
mylist = [x*x for x in range(3)]
for i in mylist:
    print(i)
```

code for generator:

```
mygenerator = [x*x for x in range(3)]
for i in mygenerator:
    print(i)
```

then what is the significance?

Comment: A generator is type of an iterable. In the last code block you have 2 list comprehensions, not a single generator. Your first code is not indented correctly.

Comment: [the official Python reference on `yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr)